# Can constraints utilize the groupby (pivot) function? (scipy.optimize.minimize; SLSQP)

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, minimize

It appears that the issue with the code is my constraints.  I'm looking to model employment at the state level & sector level.  So I want to make sure that the total modelled employment for each state equals the total recorded employment for each state.

For my constraint, I join the modelled dataframe (1D) to the original table (concatenate) and perform a sum command (groupby the state code).

```
def Constraint_STBalance(x):
    TableRebuild = ST_2d_total #<-outside table, orginal data.
    TableRebuild['Table_EMP_MOD'] = x
    TableRebuild['EMPNEW'] = TableRebuild['Table_EMP_MOD'] + TableRebuild['EMP_ADJ']
    sumby2d = TableRebuild.groupby(['FIPSTATE'], as_index=False)['EMP_NEW'].sum()
    return sumby2d['EMP_NEW'] - ST_total['EMP'] #<-outside table, reference data.
```

scipy.optimize.minimize with the 'SLSQP' method returns the error code 6 which references a problem with the "LSQ matrix", which from I can determine relates to the jacobian and hessian  matrices.

I think the use of the sumby is changing the dimensions of the jacobian and hessian matrices but I admittedly am new to optimizing.  Does anyone know with 'sumby' can be used in this manner or perhaps there's some workaround I'm overlooking?

Comment: This is probably not a problem of dimensions (error should look different) but more a problem of smoothness and gradient calculation. So take a step back, check out what NLP is about (smooth optimization; compare with [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming): `for which the objective function and the constraints are twice continuously differentiable`) and try to reason about your smoothness (probably not that smooth). Also keep in mind, that this code is not reproducible for the users here and reasoning about your optimization-surface is even harder then.

Comment: Thank you, I'm taking a critical look at making sure the constraints and objectives are scalar and twice differentiated.  I'm unsure if group.by can be utilized while keeping the formula twice differential and scalar.  hm.. tough stuff - thx again.

Comment: Groupby,sum is just an awkard summation. Write things down in mathematical notation to see how to differentiate. Or better use a modeling system like AMPL or GAMS that provides automatic differentiation so you can focus on the model itself instead of on debugging gradient evaluation code, Many economists build very complex, nonlinear, models in GAMS.